# How to animate visibility of mesh in react three fiber?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, three.js, react-three-fiber

I have a 3D model. I have the access to the mesh. What I want is to animate the visibility on button click. When I press a button the mesh should be invisible but not instantly. I want to make it in an animated way. It will be invisible in some steps. Like taking 2 sec of time to be invisible with a transition. How can I do that with react three fiber? I'm new in React-three/fiber.

Code I tried:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (props.miscOpen === true) {
      Object.keys(materials).forEach(function (prop) {
        if (prop.includes("_350")) {
          gsap.to(materials[prop],{duration:5,opacity:0})
          
        }
      });
    } else {
      
    }
  }, [props.miscOpen]);
```

Comment: What have you tried alreay? Have you tried animating the mesh's material opacity property with some sort of animation library like GSAP?

Comment: I tried to set opacity with GSAP but it is not working. I dont know why

Comment: Post your code, this is not a tutorial site.

Comment: added the code I tried. If I try to change the visible property it is changing but instantly.  But I want a transition of fading out. So tried the opacity but its not working

Comment: Are you setting the material's `.transparent` property to `true`? If the material's transparent property is not set to true, the material will remain fully opaque and this value (opacity) will only affect its color. [see here](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=material#api/en/materials/Material.opacity)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I resolved it. transparency was the issue for this.

Comment: I added it as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting the material's .transparent property to true?
If the material's transparent property is not set to true, the material will remain fully opaque and this value (opacity) will only affect its color. [see here](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=material#api/en/materials/Material.opacity)